# How can I win against players wielding a Type 95?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Every time I come up against a player with a Type 95 I get my butt handed to me on a silver platter! How can I beat it? Should I just use a Type 95? Do you think they will nerf it at all?

Comment: Several sources (ie youtube videos) are saying this is overpowered. Hopefully they get it under control

Comment: You can always tell when something is OP: everyone is using it. The UMP in MW2 and the 74u for much of BlOps. If they're all using it, there's a reason.

Comment: For future reference, the Type 95 has been nerfed down as far as I can tell. It now takes 2 bursts for all but the closest of ranges. 1 burst kills only really happen now if the entire burst is a headshot(and it's not too long of range), or if it's extremely close (nearly knifing distance) and the entire burst hits their body.

Answer (score 2):

In MW3, the Type 95 is the most OP gun in the game. Sure, the M16 has slightly more range than the Type 95, but all around, the Type 95 beats it. Type 95 only takes 2 shots (body as well as head) to kill an enemy up to mid range, and that is not even one burst.  At longer ranges it is 3-4 shots (basically 2 bursts).  The M16 takes 2 shots head, 3 shots body at close to mid range, and I think 3-4 shots long as well. The Type 95 is basically the M16 of COD4 but nerfed a bit at longer ranges.

The Type 95 has a faster fire rate, slightly faster reload time, and I personally find it has lower recoil than M16, though I find it that the Type 95 has an odd iron sight.

"Beating" players using Type 95 is really based on skill, but when putting two players of about equal skill, you need to use the type 95 yourself and use quickdraw to get that first hit on him. I haven't found other great strategies yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use guns designed for the map sizes. The Type 95 isn't the best at everything, so plan based on map size. Snipers will beat it at long and Akimbos or RF SMGs have a chance at close. Try to flank and have the gunfights on your own terms instead of letting him shoot you at all. Remember, he can't kill you if he's dead already. Learn camper spots so you can avoid them, let the dirty little bastards be bored the whole game waiting for someone to come by. OR if none of this works, get a wired connection and pull host!

As for the nerf, I doubt it, because:

1. IW is lazy as is evident by the horrific lag in this game, pathetic map design, and terrible mic quality, and
2. The Type 95 doesn't really need a nerf, in my opinion, because you need to have reasonably good aim to use it and not many people really spam it. No such thing as Type 95 spray-n-pray. It they make it take 3 shots to kill close then everyone will start complaining about how it's *underpowered.*

Comment: +1 for mentioning the aim. I'm an above-average player with most guns, but I always lose with Type 95s because my initial aim sucks (I 'correct' while shooting, something that doesn't work with burst weapons)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if the guy using the Type 95 sees you first and gets aim on you, you're toast..! Be sure to always try and get the shot in first so that it creates a flinch when he tries to shoot. Suggest you use quickdraw / quickdraw pro so that you are able to ADS faster therefore getting the first shot in when you're one on one with a Type 95..

Good luck mate!

Answer (score 0):

There is no any special way of beating any other weapon. It all comes down to who was the first to the draw.
If he was first (and reasonably accurate), then he kills you instantly.
Based on specifics of your question I assume you typically wield lower powered full auto weapon. In this case if you were first, you would kill him slower, but just as assured since he wont be able to hit you due to flinching.

Now this is all nice in theory. On practice, playing in wonderful world of listen servers, who gets to be first to the draw is almost entirely random due to massive interpolation on 200ms+ connection. Unless one of you is host... then the host wins every time no matter how quick the other guy is.

Comment: He may be able to hit you if he is using the weapon specialization that reduces flinch. Additionally, I rarely play on 200+ms connections. If you can't find one less than that, it's going to suck. It will rarely throw you into one over 150ms, and usually I can find one under 100ms. If you can't find one under 100ms, I wouldn't play - you won't enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Type 95 is extremely good at close range if all 3 bullets hit - due to its low recoil and quick fire of the 3 bullets, it's likely - but it is not as good at long range as the M16, the other 3-round burst assault rifle in the game. So hitting them at range is going to give you some chance. At close range, flashing them if possible will be especially effective because they can't spray and pray like someone with an automatic weapon.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the other answers, make sure you can start shooting them before they shoot you! The Type-95 is especially good at short-range. So your best bet is to outgun them with a submachine gun with rapid fire, or an akimbo set of machine pistols. Along with that, Quickdraw can help, but Steady Aim Pro does wonders. It lets you recover from sprinting almost instantly.